# kmod-nvidia-340xx.x86_64 for centos 7 kernel 3.10.0-229.20.1.el7.x86_64

Tags: centos, centos7, nvidia

I just installed centos 7 upgraded, etc.

`>sudo yum update`
No Packages to Update
`>sudo yum upgrade`
No Packages to Upgrade

I followed the [instructions](http://elrepo.org/tiki/tiki-index.php) to install elrepo.

When I try:
`>sudo yum install kmod-nvidia-340xx.x86_64`

I get:

```
 Requires: kernel >= 3.10.0-327.el7
           Installed: kernel-3.10.0-123.el7.x86_64 (@anaconda)
               kernel = 3.10.0-123.el7
           Installed: kernel-3.10.0-229.20.1.el7.x86_64 (@updates)
               kernel = 3.10.0-229.20.1.el7
           Available: kernel-3.10.0-229.el7.x86_64 (base)
               kernel = 3.10.0-229.el7
           Available: kernel-3.10.0-229.1.2.el7.x86_64 (updates)
               kernel = 3.10.0-229.1.2.el7
           Available: kernel-3.10.0-229.4.2.el7.x86_64 (updates)
               kernel = 3.10.0-229.4.2.el7
           Available: kernel-3.10.0-229.7.2.el7.x86_64 (updates)
               kernel = 3.10.0-229.7.2.el7
           Available: kernel-3.10.0-229.11.1.el7.x86_64 (updates)
               kernel = 3.10.0-229.11.1.el7
           Available: kernel-3.10.0-229.14.1.el7.x86_64 (updates)
               kernel = 3.10.0-229.14.1.el7
           Available: kernel-debug-3.10.0-229.el7.x86_64 (base)
               kernel = 3.10.0-229.el7
           Available: kernel-debug-3.10.0-229.1.2.el7.x86_64 (updates)
               kernel = 3.10.0-229.1.2.el7
           Available: kernel-debug-3.10.0-229.4.2.el7.x86_64 (updates)
               kernel = 3.10.0-229.4.2.el7
           Available: kernel-debug-3.10.0-229.7.2.el7.x86_64 (updates)
               kernel = 3.10.0-229.7.2.el7
           Available: kernel-debug-3.10.0-229.11.1.el7.x86_64 (updates)
               kernel = 3.10.0-229.11.1.el7
           Available: kernel-debug-3.10.0-229.14.1.el7.x86_64 (updates)
               kernel = 3.10.0-229.14.1.el7
           Available: kernel-debug-3.10.0-229.20.1.el7.x86_64 (updates)
               kernel = 3.10.0-229.20.1.el7
```

I don't think i can upgrade my kernel...so how do i find kmod-nvidia for my kernel

Comment: You should report this to elrepo. They've built against a pre-release kernel which isn't officially available yet.

Comment: @MichaelHampton ok, i've never done that before i'll try to figure it out.  Is there a version of the elrepo i could use via yum?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears that elrepo has built their kernel module against the (pre-release, at the time) CentOS 7.2 kernel, 3.10.0-327.

```
[mirror@saurok mirrors]$ ls -l centos/7.2.1511/os/x86_64/Packages/kernel-3.10.0-327.el7.x86_64.rpm
-rw-rw-r--. 2 mirror mirror 34633276 Nov 25 09:48 centos/7.2.1511/os/x86_64/Packages/kernel-3.10.0-327.el7.x86_64.rpm
```

I'm not *entirely* sure why they did that; it may be worth asking them directly if you're curious.

CentOS 7.2 is now becoming available on mirrors worldwide (it landed on my local mirror a few hours ago) and you should be able to access it within the next few days.